# android replacing fragment on event from another fragment

Tags: android

any android developer here? i need to ask something regarding communication between different fragment like i select something from list of fragment one and on that even fragment two is replaced with another layout?

i have listview adapter in fragment 1 and its view in fragment two. 
in fragment one i have already implement onClickListener and switch by getting the position from clicklistener method. i used fragment manager but not getting the way i want. 
please reply with code and explanation! 
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what actually you want and can you post something that you had done till.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you're trying to implement is a ["master-detail" flow](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#master-detail). Let us call your first Fragment the list Fragment and your second Fragment the detail Fragment and let us assume that they both exist within a parent Activity.

To establish communication between your list Fragment and your detail Fragment, you could define a callback interface that the parent activity of both Fragments implement. So, in your list Fragment, you would have:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    // Create a reference to your callback
    private ListItemSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Define your callback interface
    public interface ListItemSelectedListener {
        onListItemSelected(int position, Object data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Send the event to the parent activity
        mCallback.onListItemSelected(position, getData(position));
    }
}
```

Then, your parent activity implements the callback listener and triggers a change in the detail Fragment when necessary.

```
public class MasterDetailActivity extends Activity
    implements MyListFragment.ListItemSelectedListener {

    //....
    // Implement the callback method defined in the interface
    public void onListItemSelected(int position, Object data) {
        // Get a reference to your detail Fragment
        DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_fragment);

        /* This is assuming both the list fragment and the detail fragment
         * exist within the parent Activity
         */
        if (detailFragment != null) {
            detailFragment.changeDetailView(position, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Check out Google's [document on Fragment communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to learn more.

Comment: thnx for reply.. i will try to implement this... appreciate you sir!